# substr_count and an array as a needle

Tags: php

How to use substr_count with an array as a needle. Like this:

```
substr_count($str, array('find_this', 'or_find_this'));
```

Comment: Can you give an example for `$str` and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

You could use implode() to create a string of the array and create a regex kind of thing.

```
$array = array('find_this', 'or_find_this');
$string = implode('|', $array);
$count = count(preg_grep("/($string)/", $str));
echo $count;
```

Comment: preg_grep has an array for second parameter. Supposing $str is a string I would use preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through them and add the substr_count() to the total count. A ready example is in the php manual page,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php#74952