# PHP checking multiple words in a long one word string

Tags: php

using strpos, I can find one word in a string, but how can I find many words?

I know how to do it when the string contains words that are separated with space, but for example, if I have `array('hi','how','are','you')` and a string `$string = 'hihowareyoudoingtoday?'`
How can I return the total amount found to match?

Comment: Using a loop and a counter

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: @exussum i thought of that, would that in any way effect speed performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [substr\_count and an array as a needle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3666082)

Comment: @derp i have a whole website built, I rather optimize now and save the headache for later to focus on more important issues

Comment: @mario, can you explain how?

Comment: @user3673223 Yes, I could.

Comment: @mario, ready when you are.. Edit: oh downvote.. good reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` that returns the number of matches:

```
$words = array('hi','how','are','you');

$nb = preg_match_all('~' . implode('|', $words) . '~', $string, $m);

print_r($m[0]);

echo "\n$nb";
```

`preg_match_all` is a function that searches all occurences of a pattern in a string. In the present example, the pattern is:

```
~hi|how|are|you~
```

the `~` is only a pattern delimiter.

`|` is a logical OR

Note that the search is performed form left to right character by character in the string and each alternatives are tested until one matches. So the first word that matches in a position is stored as a match result (into `$m`).
Understanding this mechanism is important. For example, if you have the string `baobab` and the pattern `~bao|baobab~`, the result will be only `bao` since it is the first tested alternative.

In other words, if you want to obtain the largest words first, you need to sort the array by size before.

Comment: how will it know where to divide the long string? I don't quite get  it if you don't mind explaining

Comment: @user3673223: it doesn't know! It walks character by character and tests each possible substring. When a substring matches, it advances to the next characters and continues until the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in this case:

Example:

```
$haystack = 'hihowareyoudoingtoday?';
$needles = array('hi','how','are','you');
$matches = 0;
foreach($needles as $needle) { // create a loop, foreach string
    if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) { // use stripos and compare it in the parent string
        $matches++; // if it matches then increment.
    }
}

echo $matches; // 4
```

Comment: would that in any way effect speed performance looping through like that compare to checking one word at a time?

Comment: @user3673223 how many strings are you going to compare? strings can be up to 2GB. is your project going to reach that? its okay to use this